# Footer using HTML & CSS-

Tags: html, css, web, dreamweaver, footer

I'm creating a website and I have a footer at the bottom of the page. I want to place the text at some above from the current position, without increasing the height of the footer. Can someone tell me how to do this please?

Current HTML is

```
<div class="footer">
<ul id="footer">
<li> <img src="Images/facebook.png" />  <img src="Images/twitter.png" />  </li>
<li> Jewllery</li>
<li> ADDRESS </li>      
<li> TEL PHONE</li>
</ul> </div>
```

and the current `css` is

```
.footer         

{
text-align:centre;
background-color:#C8C8C8;
color:#000000;
}


#footer li      
{
display:inline-block;
padding-right:3em;
}
```

Comment: Can you try again to describe exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to move the text into the middle of the footer? [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/28HVP/) Like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a negative margin-top like this:

```
.footer {
     margin-top: -3em;
}
```

Edit:
What he tried to do is move the text inside the footer up, not the footer itself.
So you have to give the li-element a negative margin-top:

```
#footer li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I've tried this and it moves the whole footer up and makes my footer and another div over flow but I want there to be a gap... Is there any way of just making the content move up without moving the position of the footer or making it bigger?

Comment: You can give the text inside the footer a css-class (for example p.footer), which has a negative margin-top. Or you can give your footer li class the negative margin-top which should also work. see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/28HVP/2/

Comment: You're welcome :-) I've updated my answer so people don't have to look at the comments to see the right way to do this.

Comment: @user3046451 Care to explain what worked? Im curious... Also, saw the update to your question and now it makes sense. Let me be the first to say... using `margin-top: -50px;` is a bad way to this. I would use something like that when I need to quickly see what something would look like in that position.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try

```
.footer {
  margin-top: -1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you said im taking it as (move the text in the footer up, without actually effecting the footer)

set the child footers margin as a negative.

```
#footer{
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```